# Java command line argument test

Tags: java, arrays, string, command-line

When I run the following code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println("testing");
        System.out.println(args[0] == "testing");
    }
}
```

using

> java Test testing

at the command line, it prints the following:

testing
testing
false

Why is the third printed line not 'true' when printed lines 1 and 2 seem to be the same?

Edit:
Thanks for your replies - that's answered my query. I have a follow up query, which is: if == compares the String references, how can I find out what those references are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Always use `.equals()` when comparing strings in Java.

`System.out.println(args[0].equals("testing"));`

Answer (score 0):

== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.

You want to do this instead:

```
System.out.println(args[0].equals("testing"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("testing")==0